# Change Orientation forcefully

Tags: iphone

In my app, While playing video user can play in  full screen in both orientation landscape and portrait. But while move back to original position from full screen, i want to change my controller's orientation to portrait if its running in landscape.

Its working fine if i push that controller, but i have to present it. So its not working with presented controller.

I m using code as below to make it portrait.

```
  [appdel.navigationController.presentedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].self.delegate.window addSubview:[appdel.navigationController.presentedViewController.view];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi you can refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847652/portrait-mode-app-return-to-portrait-mode-after-landscape-fullscreen-movieplaye/10848655#10848655
this works fine for me but someone says apple reject app but i have uploaded more then two app with this... so Wish you best of luck for this...

Answer (score 0):

see in case of presenting the controller when u come in previous controller the
viewWillApear: of previous method will call so change your orientation in viewWillApear: mthod

Comment: ok.But, I have to change orientation in same controller, not while go to previous controller.

Comment: previous means that controller from where you have presented another controller....

Comment: yes got, but my issue is that eg., I have presented playerVC from tempVC. Now in playerVC while playing video in full screen i have rotate device to landscape. Now if i move back to normal view from full screen i want to change it portrait. Still I m in playerVC. got?

Comment: while moving to normal view your video is continuing then it will handle automatically and if its finished then try to rotate when your video playing finished call will call